# Using dash plotly treemap, how do I track selected data?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, treemap

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70647874/python-plotly-dash-treemap-get-selected-child-label) to track selected leaf node. But I am unable to make it work.  I get a callback error and nothing prints to terminal.  Could someone help me correct the code?

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels = ["Eve","Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parents = ["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve"],
    root_color="lightgrey",
    # dragmode=False
))

fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))

app = dash.Dash()


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='basic-interactions',
        figure=fig)
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("selected-data", "children"),
    dash.dependencies.Input("basic-interactions", "clickData"),
)
def update_other_figure(selected_data):
    print('test')
    print(selected_data)
    return selected_data
    # Do something with the data...
```

> Attempting to connect a callback Output item to component:
> "selected-data" but no components with that id exist in the layout.
>
> If you are assigning callbacks to components that are generated by
> other callbacks (and therefore not in the initial layout), you can
> suppress this exception by setting
> `suppress_callback_exceptions=True`. This ID was used in the
> callback(s) for Output(s):   selected-data.children

Answer (score 1):

In the dash app layout you have only one graph component. In your callback function you have declared one output component with id "selected-data", which is absent in layout. The layout should have another component with id "selected-data", whose children property will be set by the callback function. For example,one label component can be added in the layout.

```
app.layout = html.Div([html.Label(id="selected-data"),
        dcc.Graph(
            id='basic-interactions',
            figure=fig)
    ])
```

This will show you the selected clickData info in your page.